# mysql datetime update to one column

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have made a really silly mistake of having a seperate date and time field in my DB. I really need to put these together and just have one field (datetime) Luckily these are individually in the corect format. Is there a way I can di an SQL statement to take the date, time (with a space inbetween) and input these in to the new datetime field? I have around 3000 records in this table so really dont want to do it by hand.

Thanks

Richard

Comment: You should see what I had to do with one datetime and 4 integer fields to make a single datetime field. T'was tricky, I tell you that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

run:

```
UPDATE dates SET datettime_field = CONCAT(date_field,' ', time_field);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [CONCAT_WS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) to do a string concatenation:

```
UPDATE table
SET newfield = CONCAT_WS(' ', oldfield1, oldfield2);
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is:

```
update table set datetime_field = addtime(date_field, time_field);
```